# Difference between shadow and content selector

Tags: html, css-selectors, polymer, polymer-1.0

What is the difference `content` selector and `shadow` selector in polymer? I can use `content` to pierce the `dom` of any element like in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pbRXKY?editors=1000) and vise-versa is also true i.e. i can use `shadow` selector to style distributed children of any element(I tried it with `card-content` class in `paper-card`)

Answer (score 0):

That might be a polyfill limitation that they can replace each other (not tried myself).

- `::shadow` is to pierce from the outside of a custom element into its shadow DOM.
  `::shadow` is deprecated
- `::content` is to style projected content (`<content></content>`) from the parent component of the `<content>` tag.
  `<content></content>` is also deprecated (going to be replaced by `<slot>`)
  See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content

Comment: It's not because of polyfill. I ran my code in chrome without `webcomponentsjs` and still i can see same behavior

Comment: Seems you also need to enable full shadow DOM https://plnkr.co/edit/iMTwLuBIlFdfFoHptyGe?p=preview

Comment: Yes, i noticed that. If i enable shadow DOM then this behavior is not observed.

Comment: So its a polyfill issue because there is no native shady DOM.

Comment: If i am right shady DOM does not come from `webcomponentsjs`, but from `polymer`. So doesn't this make it issue of of shady-dom rather than polyfill.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what exactly is from polyfills or Polymer but natively from the browser it is treated as expected.